# Why is my "at" command in terminal not functioning?

Tags: macos, bash, command-line, terminal

I'm trying to use `echo "haha" | at 20:30` for instance to make my command execute in a few minutes.

But the command never executes:

```
$ date
Tue  3 Feb 2015 20:47:22 AST
$ echo "test" | at 20:48
job 5 at Tue Feb  3 20:48:00 2015
$ date
Tue  3 Feb 2015 20:48:05 AST
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you think you're doing anything wrong? `atd` runs commands as subprocesses of its daemon -- there wouldn't be output to your terminal even if the `test` command _did_ have any output (and it doesn't).

Comment: Keep in mind also -- `echo "test" | at 20:48` doesn't send `echo "test"` to `at`, it sends `test` to at; a shell pipe connects the **output** of the command on the left to the input of the command on the right, and the output of `echo "test"` is `test`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy So how do I send a command to at?

Comment: Well, the normal approach would be to use a quoted heredoc, but I'd need to write a full answer to describe that.

Comment: Geez, all I want is to make a command execute at a certain time, a few minutes from now normally. Am I over complicating this?

Comment: It's not like a quoted heredoc is _hard_. I've demonstrated invoking `at` with one -- it's all of three lines.

Comment: What's your real-world use case here? Do you _need_ terminal output? (It's a bit problematic if you do -- how do you guarantee that the terminal window that ran the `at` command is still open? What do you want to do if it's not?)

Comment: I have a Ruby script I'd like to execute at a certain time of the night when I'm sleeping (say 3:30 AM). I guess I'm just really confused with why when I echo something to the terminal it will just print it out, but if I pipe it to something it seemingly interprets it as a command.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70182/discussion-between-charles-duffy-and-doug-smith).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A conventional use would be more like:

```
at 20:48 <<'EOF'
echo "test" >/tmp/hello_world
EOF
```

Check `/tmp/hello_world` after the time scheduled has passed.

---

In this case, what you're sending to the stdin of the `at` command is the entire document -- everything between the `<<'EOF'` and the following `EOF`.

Answer (score 4):

Your command:

```
echo "test" | at 20:48
```

tells `at` to execute the command `test` with no arguments.  It is a shell built-in that runs, but fails.  Try:

```
test
echo $?
```

It yields `1` for me, indicating failure.

You probably had in mind something like:

```
echo "echo test" | at 20:48
```

Now you just need to know where the output will go.  `/dev/null` is a reasonable guess.  So, try:

```
echo "echo test > /tmp/x39.214" | at 20:48
```

Then, when 20:48 (or your chosen new time) has come and gone, look for the file `/tmp/x39.214` to contain the line `test`.

The `at` command reads its standard input for a series of commands to execute.  They're run with your environment, but with no terminal connected (so `/dev/null` is standard input, output, error — or, if it isn't, you'll be getting the outputs in email).  Your command, therefore, has to arrange to store its outputs where you can find it.  A fixed name like `/tmp/x39.214` is not a good idea, but you need to be able to determine where the file will go and what the name will be.  Often, the name will include a time.

Because `at` reads standard input, you can redirect standard input any way you like, with a here doc, or a here string, or from a file, or with a pipe, to name but four mechanisms.

```
$ echo "echo test >/tmp/x39.214" > file1.txt
$ at 20:48 < file1.txt
$ at 20:48 <<'EOF'
> echo test >/tmp/x39.214
> EOF
$ at 20:48 <<< 'echo test >/tmp/x39.214'
$ cat file1.txt | at 20:48
$
```

<sup>I've omitted the output from `at` for each of the commands above.</sup>

You can use `at -l` to list jobs and see what would be run.

Comment: `echo "test"` in the terminal works though, why it would think I'm trying to execute the "test" command?

Comment: `echo "test"` echoes just `test`, doesn't it?  So that's what `at` sees as its standard input.  It does not see the `echo` at all.

Comment: I was under the impression the `at` part just schedules the previous command at a certain time. What exactly is it doing? If I write `echo "echo test"` in the terminal it says "echo test". So why would it do what I want into a file?

Comment: It schedules the standard output of the previous command.  What would you get from `echo "test" | cat`, for example?  The answer's `test` (without the quotes).  So that's the input that `at` sees.  There's no special magic there.  You can have a program generate an enormous shell script, or a single line command, and feed that output to the `at` command.  You've chosen a very simple single line command.

Comment: @DougSmith, the reason it won't write output to the terminal is that the `at` command schedules commands to be run by the _at daemon_, and the _at daemon_ isn't connected to any terminal at all. (Of course, this also means that your system has to be configured to have the at daemon running -- if it isn't, commands scheduled by `at` will never be invoked).